# Effective javascript book having trouble understanding item 13(Iffy)

Tags: javascript, closures

Trying to read this wonderful book of effective javascript(but I am still novice)..

In item 13, it talks about immediately invoked function expression to create local scopes.

I unfortunately however cannot wrap my head around below example

```
function wrapElements(a) {
  var result = [], i, n;
  for ( i = 0, n = a.length; i < n; i++ ) {
      result[i] = function() { return a[i]; };
  }
  return result;
}

var wrapped = wrapElements([10,20,30,40,50]);
var f = wrapped[0];
f();  // undefined....
```

I really try to read that page many times but I still don't understand

Especially below statement from the book.

> The bug in the program comes from the fact that the programmer apparently expected the function to store the value of i at the time of the nested function was created. But in fact, it contains a reference to i. Since the value of i changes after each function is created, the inner functions end up seeing the final value of i. This is the key point about the closures.
>   Closures store their outer variable by reference, not by value.

I honestly think I understand closure storing info by reference and not by value but I honestly cannot relate them to above paragraphs.
Can someone please explain this to me in easier terms or point me to article which does this? I was not able to find any that was easy to understand.

Thank you for your time in advance!!

Answer (score 2):

Let me see if I can help you understand a little.  The concept of Immediately-Invoked Function Expressions or (the popular term back when I learned them) Self-Executing Anonymous Functions can be a difficult one to grasp and I recommend that you have a solid knowledge of JavaScript before really digging in, but I may be able to help explain it to you in a way that will help you understand.

So - let's start by examining a normal function declaration that can be done one of two ways:

```
function someFunction (param1, param2) {
    //do stuff
};
```

OR

```
var someFunction = function (param1, param2) {
    //do stuff
};
```

And to invoke this function, you would call it like so:

```
someFunction("param1value", "param2value");
```

Which is great and works exactly how it's supposed to.  But what if you need a function that executes or invokes immediately when it's ran, and don't want to add an object to the global namespace?  Here's the real benefit of an IIFE (SEAF).  Here is the basic structure of an anonymous function:

```
(function () {

})();
```

The first set of parenthesis after `(function () {` pass parameters into the scope of the function.  The second set of parenthesis `})();` are used to invoke the function and pass parameters into the function.  Wrapping the function declaration in parenthesis makes the function anonymous and allows it to execute or invoke immediately.

Let's take a very basic beginning framework example and explain in a little more detail:

```
(function (window, undefined) {

})(window);
```

I remember when I first saw this, I couldn't figure what was going on here and what the point was...  This function accepts two parameters to pass into the scope of the function, a window object and an undefined object.  `(function (window, undefined) {`  Then when we call it, we pass in only one window object (the global window scope).  `})(window);`  To help you understand, this would be like writing a function and executing it like this:

```
function doStuff (window, undefined) {
    //do stuff here
};
doStuff(window);
```

So why don't people just write their code this way instead of worrying about these IIFE's?  Well, writing your functions this way, could clog up your global scope, meaning that now you have a `doStuff()` object defined that is available across the scope of your entire project.  If you have a really large project or framework, you typically only want to expose one object to the global scope, and keep everything else anonymous so it doesn't overwrite or get overwritten by additional code that may also be included in the application.

This is really the basics, but to help you understand the syntax a little more, let me do a real basic working example for you, just to help you wrap your head around the concept.  In this example, as soon as the code runs, we're just going to multiply two numbers, whichever two numbers you pass into the function.  Then we're going to output the result to a text box with the id "result".  You can play around with it here:  http://jsfiddle.net/k7f4n0mk/

```
(function (number1, number2) {
    document.getElementById("result").value = (number1 * number2);
})(5, 10);
```

If we were to write this without an IIFE, you would first have to define the function, then invoke it and it would look like this:

```
function multiply(number1, number2) {
    document.getElementById("result").value = (number1 * number2);
};
multiply(5, 10);
```

You can see this example here:  http://jsfiddle.net/k7f4n0mk/1/

Both examples produce the exact same result, and I'm assuming that you're fairly comfortable with the second one since it's one of the very basics of the language, so why should you worry about this whole new way to write a function if you're old way works just fine?  Well, again, this goes back to keeping the global scope clean, and protecting the local scope.

Everyone is pretty familiar with the jQuery javascript library.  The entire context of jQuery is wrapped in an IIFE and only the jQuery and the alias $ object are exposed to the global scope - that's pretty impressive for everything that jQuery does.  Well, if jQuery didn't have this IIFE syntax, then every function that they declared would be available to the global scope and could easily be overwritten by an unknowing user.  They could overwrite any of the function that jQuery uses and completely break the library - so we want to protect all of the functions that jQuery uses (local scope) and keep the global scope clean by only exposing the necessary objects (jQuery and $).

I know this has been a really long answer, but I hope that I have been able to help you gain a little more understanding on this subject.  Let me know if you have any other questions.

**-EDIT-**

To the point of your question - let me see if I can help explain in greater detail.

Here is the code that you are using:

```
function wrapElements(a) {
    var result = [], i, n;
    for (i = 0, n = a.length; i < n; i++) {
        result[i] = function () { return a[i]; };
    }
    return result;
}

var wrapped = wrapElements([10, 20, 30, 40, 50]);
var f = wrapped[0];
f();
```

Now, when you call `var wrapped = wrapElements([10, 20, 30, 40, 50]);`

wrapped is now referencing an array of functions, because that's what you're returning in your for loop:

```
wrapped = [function () { return a[i]; },function () { return a[i]; },function () { return a[i]; },function () { return a[i]; },function () { return a[i]; }]
```

Then, when you call `var f = wrapped[0]`, f becomes a reference to the first function in the array

```
f = function () { return a[i]; }
```

So, what you are doing in this code, is adding a new function to the array in your loop.  If you try to call the function, `a` and `i` will be undefined which is why you are receiving an undefined error.

To achieve the desired results, the code would look like this:

```
function wrapElements(a) {
    var result = [], i, n;
    for (i = 0, n = a.length; i < n; i++) {
        result[i] = a[i];
    }
    return result;
}

var wrapped = wrapElements([10, 20, 30, 40, 50]);
var f = wrapped[0];
```

I hope this helps your understanding a little more.  Please let me know if you need any further assistance.

Comment: This really helps me understand Iffy.. Really like your example and helps me.  I however still cannot connect this to my example...

Comment: are you missing anything in your example?  could you double check it?  the example you provided is not an IIFE, but a standard function.  is there additional code above in the example that you didn't include?

Comment: I am so sorry.. I think I understand iffy enough w/ your excellent explanation. However, what I am puzzled is in fact with the example I gave.. I don't understand why i=5 by the time       result[i] = function() { return a[i]; };
 is ran.. I understand in settimeout and set interval case, but why also in this case? Is this just simply how for loop works in javascript?

Comment: Ah, I see now, I misunderstood.  You're talking about passing variables by value vs. by reference.  There is a really excellent post here that may help you understand more:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6605640/javascript-by-reference-vs-by-value  If you need additional help, let me know and I'll try to explain it a different way.  Thanks!

Comment: So I think I understand now although I am not 100% sure..  because closure keep outer variable by reference, variable 'i' is always changing.. and even though at the time of creation of each function, i has the right value but at the end, all i will be pointed to same value(which is 5).. am I  looking this righ?

Answer (score 1):

This is a very common bug. Let me simplify it for you.

The following program should alert `1`, `2` and `3`:

```js
for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
  setTimeout(function () {
    alert(i);
  }, 10);
}
```

However, as you can see it alerts `4` 3 times instead. What's happening is that by the time the function given to `setTimeout` is called the value of `i` has changed. That's the same problem that you are facing.

To solve this problem we make use of immediately invoked function expressions (IIFEs).

```js
for (var i = 1; i <=3; i++) {
  (function (new_i) {
    setTimeout(function () {
      alert(new_i);
    }, 10);
  }(i));
}
```

By using an IIFE we're creating a new variable called `i` whose value is the that of the old `i`. Now when the old `i` changes, the new `i` remains the same. Hence we get the expected result.

A better way to write this would be to use the `with` statement to create a new `i` as follows:

```js
for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
  with ({ new_i: i }) {
    setTimeout(function () {
      alert(new_i);
    }, 10);
  }
}
```

Using `with` is better than the IIFE for 2 reasons:

1. It's cleaner and easier to read and understand.
2. It's faster because no function is being invoked. Function invocation is slow.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I get the SetTimeout and setinterval as none blocking so the var counts goes up and comes back to setimeout function once "i" testing is no longer valid, but why does my example run it similar way? Is this how javascript runs all for loop?